# Can I create my own Wi-Fi network on a pre-existing router?

Tags: router, ieee-802.11

I am a student, and the Wi-Fi at my school is very spotty. My laptop is connected to the Ethernet so that's no problem but my phone cannot connect to any of three Wi-Fi networks. Lots of people have this same problem too. I was wondering if there is a way to create my own wireless Internet network "on top of" the spotty Wi-Fi network (i.e.- have the traffic from my phone go through the same router but on a different network). Thank you very much for any advice you can provide!

Comment: Questions to networks that are not controlled by you are sadly off-topic here.

Comment: Also contacting your schools IT administration would be more appropriate in addition to trying to bypass the security of the WIFI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid your question is rather confusing. How exactly are you planning to access the school network via the same router but on another SSID? If you have infrastructure gear on your school, perhaps you could address the quality issue by doing some simple tests on the VLAN to which wireless clients connect but if you want further insight on what to do you have to provide detailed info about the network structure, type of device, make & model, some configs, vlan info and if whether you have access to these devices or not. Perhaps by just looking into the "spottiness" of your wireless can simplify the work you would have to put on this.